# How to embed all numbers within $ $

Tags: regex, interpreter, tex

I am preparing my thesis in latex. I want to embed all of real numbers (numbers with decimal points) in table environment within a $ $. What is the best approach to do so. There are many tables and my files are saved in utf-8 encoding.

Example:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{پایگاه داده‌ی نمونه استفاده شده در مثال  \ref{ex:exp1}، (آ)  پایگاه داده‌ی اصلی ، (ب) نسخه‌ی 3-بی نامی}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|r|r|r|r|r|}
\cline{1-2}\cline{4-5}    681.00 & 404.00 &       &  327.55 & 280.92    \\
%
%
%
\multicolumn{3}{c}{(آ)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(ب)} 

\end{tabular}%
\label{tab:LF_3}
\end{table}
```

must be changed to

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{پایگاه داده‌ی نمونه استفاده شده در مثال  \ref{ex:exp1}، (آ)  پایگاه داده‌ی اصلی ، (ب) نسخه‌ی 3-بی نامی}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|r|r|r|r|r|}
\cline{1-2}\cline{4-5}    $681.00$ & $404.00$ &       &  $327.55$ & $280.92$    \\
%
%
%
\multicolumn{3}{c}{(آ)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(ب)} 

\end{tabular}%
\label{tab:LF_3}
\end{table}
```

Thanks

Comment: In have tried some solutions related to TeX sytem. I defined a new column type, but it has its own problems with headers. I want an intelligent replace tool to replace all numbers "N" within tables by "$N$". I think it must be simple, but not sure.

Comment: @remo Maybe [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/112576/31395) on [tex.se] will be useful to you.

Comment: RegEx: `(\b\d*?\.\d*\b)` replacement string `\$\1\$`

Comment: Dear jbarker2160, Please provide a more detailed answer to set it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a new column type:

```
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{${}}r<{{}$}@{}}
```

Now simply change `r` to `R`.

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{پایگاه داده‌ی نمونه استفاده شده در مثال  \ref{ex:exp1}، (آ)  پایگاه داده‌ی اصلی ، (ب) نسخه‌ی 3-بی نامی}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|R|R|R|R|R|}
\cline{1-2}\cline{4-5}    681.00 & 404.00 &       &  327.55 & 280.92    \\
%
%
%
\multicolumn{3}{c}{(آ)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(ب)} 

\end{tabular}%
\label{tab:LF_3}
\end{table}
```